# How to run DHCPcd on interface eth1 only

Tags: dhcp, interface, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have several network interfaces - eth0, eth1.
ETH0 is connected to the isolated local network (with switch) and has 2 static IP addresses. It was configured using `/etc/network/interfaces` file and everything works pretty good.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.54.254
gateway 192.168.54.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255

auto eth0:1

iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.168.110
gateway 192.168.168.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Interface ETH1 has to be connected to the Internet and need to use DHCP to get right IP address from the main router. When I run `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd.service` it is clearly visible that dhcpcd conflicting with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
Jun 03 13:09:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Jun 03 13:09:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[1210]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Jun 03 13:09:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[1210]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Jun 03 13:09:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[1210]: DHCP client or static address
```

However, I have found one solution which works, but I am not sure if it is considered to be the best practice. When I execute `sudo dhcpcd eth1` then I can start DHCP on eth1 only. My plan is to create a system service which will execute `sudo dhcpcd eth1` on every startup.

I have seen on the internet that some people can execute `sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd@eth1.service`, but I don't have such a service, and I am getting an error:

`Failed to enable unit: Unit file dhcpcd@eth1.service does not exist.`

**Is my approach with creating a custom service with `sudo dhcpcd eth1` correct?**

Comment: Why don't you set it up in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Would be nice. Could you share an example how to set DHCP client in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: How about RTFM? That's really very basic thing. `man interfaces` and official Debian manuals are way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your approach isn't correct. Raspbian uses dhcpcd instead of `/etc/network/interfaces` (which is considered deprecated) by default. But as you've already configured your statics IPs through that file, you can still add `eth1` to it and enable DHCP for it. I.e. old-style, like this:

```
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Just add those lines to the end of your `/etc/network/interfaces` and reboot.

This is actually considered a better approach from the Debian "makers" and dhcpcd.conf are considered unsafe. It also seems that it doesn't allows to create aliases in a normal way.

Or instead if you prefer to stick with dhcpcd, you can tell it not to mess with eth0 and only configure DHCP on eth1 in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

Please also see this question on the issue: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45330/set-multiple-static-ip-in-dhcpcd-conf-raspbian-8-jessie

Comment: Spent 1.5 day to solve this problem. Thank you a lot for your advice. Works like a charm